# NetBeans cannot open output file and permission denied

Tags: c, netbeans

I am new to NetBeans and I am learning C with it.While I was coding,when I run the source file,the console gave me this problem.

```
   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/bolum3ornek1.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/bolum3ornek1.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/pc/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Bolum3Ornek1'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/pc/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Bolum3Ornek1'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

There are 2 errors and one code that says "permission denied".I don't know why did this happen and I can't run codes now.Could you help me?

Comment: try running the program as administrator

Comment: Could it be possible that you have an earlier version of the executable still running?  I don't know the Windows internals, but for a long time it was not possible to write into an executable file that was running a process.  Try to check on this, as normally you should have permissions to write on the file.

Answer (score 1):

The linker message says that it cannot open the `.exe` file for writing. For me, it is clear that you should have permissions to write it, as you have already written the first version. Or not?  This is your executable file, and that is the last step to get a runnable program.  So the message says that it couldn't be able to open it for writing.  This can be due to two things:

- The first is that you actually don't have permissions to write the program in the folder you selected to store the program, but this his highly improbable, as I assume you have followed the standard steps to install Netbeans.
- The second is the most probable.  You have a previous version of the executable still running on the system, and the windows kernel doesn't allow you to open it for writing while it remains running.  If this is the case, stop all running instances of the program before recompiling or rename (move the `.exe` file to another folder) the executable so netbeans doesn't clash again with the same output file.

For the comments you have received: if the problem is this, then running netbeans as the administrator will be nonsense, as the administrator cannot either write on a running program's `.exe` file.  The reason for this is that the kernel doesn't save a copy of the program text, so it has to maintain the file immutable while the program is running or bad things would happen.